# Element type "category" must not be declared more than once

Tags: xml, dtd, dita

I have a DTD file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--=========================
XML Construct Domain Module
==========================-->
<!ENTITY % category "category">
<!ENTITY % pattern "pattern">
<!ENTITY % template "template">

<!ENTITY % category.content "((pattern)?|(template)*)">
<!ENTITY % category.attribute " ">
<!ELEMENT category %category.content;>
<!ATTLIST category %category.attribute;>
<!ATTLIST category %global-atts; class CDATA "+ topic/foreign aiml-d/category">

<!ENTITY % pattern.content "(#PCDATA)">
<!ENTITY % pattern.attribute " ">
<!ELEMENT pattern %pattern.content;>
<!ATTLIST pattern %pattern.attribute;>
<!ATTLIST pattern %global-atts; class CDATA "+ topic/foreign aiml-d/pattern">

<!ENTITY % template.content "(#PCDATA)*">
<!ENTITY % template.attribute " ">
<!ELEMENT template %template.content;>
<!ATTLIST template %template.attribute;>
<!ATTLIST template %global-atts; class CDATA "+ topic/foreign aiml-d/template">
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept SYSTEM "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\dita-ot-3.0\plugins\org.dita.docbook-aiml\resource\concept.dtd">
<concept id="topicid">
   <title>Test concept</title>
    <conbody>
        <p> 
                 <category>
                    <pattern>WHAT IS DITA</pattern>
                     <template>DITA is kind of content organization stucture.</template>
                 </category>
        </p>
     </conbody>
</concept>
```

When I validate my XML file, I got the error message that "Element type "category" must not be declared more than once." But I have checked the file, I didn't declare it twice. I can't figure out what's wrong with the file.

I have tried the solutions that proposed on the StackOverflow, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You should check all the imported entities, especially .ent and .mod files, because `category`is an element that indeed already exists in standard DITA, in the `concept/proolg/metadata` block (see https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/category.html). It seems you are trying to create a new element with the same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. It works when I rename the new element.@potame